# Find ThreeJS coordinates in Panoramic GUI?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have played with ThreeJS a little in the past and am on a new project trying to setup hotspots in a panoramic. I remember using the camera dolly: http://davidpaulrosser.github.io/threejs-camera-dolly/ to get a nice visual of camera locations, but has anyone worked out one that would let you get the xyz coordinates if for instance on this ThreeJS example http://threejs.org/examples/css3d_panorama.html you wanted to place a hotspot on the road.

It could use the same thing as the dat gui that the camera dolly uses, or be a ball you drag around that reports it's location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you just want to be able to convert from a panoramic image to 3d location, so you can save something there and render it later? Something like this will give you the location you need..

https://jsfiddle.net/mz7Lv9dt/1   (**edit:** fixed a typo)

The part that probably interests you is here:

```
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
raycaster.setFromCamera( uv, cam );
return raycaster.intersectObjects( objects );
```

Drag the green ball around to get its location (always set to unit length of one)

If I totally answered wrong let me know.

Comment: Thank you so much Eric, that works great in Chrome. On my PC it didn't let me drag in Firefox, which may only be something wrong with my computer but thought I would mention it in case someone else thinks it isn't working.

Comment: Oh my bad. https://jsfiddle.net/mz7Lv9dt/1/. In my "MouseMoveObject" function i called the event "e", but tried to pass it into ray_tracing with the name "event". Pretty interesting it actually worked in chrome..