# Find Coordinates in Spherical ThreeJS Pano

Tags: javascript, three.js

I had asked this question before here: "[Find ThreeJS coordinates in Panoramic GUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34664934/find-threejs-coordinates-in-panoramic-gui)" and got a great answer from Eric. The issue I am having is that I purchased a Ricoh Theta S camera that saves files as spherical images.

I transitioned the code over to use a ball instead of a cube, all seems to be working fine except I can't find the ball to drag around to find coordinates using this code:

```
            var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.02, 32, 32 );
            var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0x00bb00} );
            ball = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
            ball.position.x = 0.0
            ball.position.y = 0.0
            ball.position.z = 0.3
            scene.add( ball );
```

I am not sure how to tell if the green ball (from the previous example) is too small, or too big to be seen. Am I too close to it, or is it located outside of the sphere that has the panoramic texture on it?

Here is the new example: https://jsfiddle.net/oo2ja3a6/2/

Answer (score 0):

The secret ended up being using `camera.position.x=20` to put myself outside the sphere. Then I could see the green ball and could start adjusting it's size and position before moving back to the middle. The working example is here:
https://jsfiddle.net/oo2ja3a6/4/